# Add Different Class on Different Ul in twenty-twentyone theme

Tags: menus, navigation, sub-menu, theme-twenty-twenty-one

I'm creating a custom menu with wp_nav_menu. I want to add different classes on menu and submenu which are coming under different `li`, but unable to find a solution. Can anyone help me to figure out this question. I am sharing the HTML part which I am trying to convert for making menu dynamic.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home </a></li>
<li class="menu-dropdown"><a href="#">Supplies <i class="ion-ios-arrow-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Chemicals</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-dropdown"><a href="#">More <i class="ion-ios-arrow-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-dropdown position-static"><a href="#">Supplies <i class="ion-ios-arrow-down"></i></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu sub-menu-2">
                <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Chemicals</a></li>
                
            </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li><a href="#">Blogs </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us </a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Code that I am using in my `site-nav.php` is

```
$args = array(
    'menu' => 'primary-menu',
    'container' => '',
    'depth' => 3,
    'fallback_cb'  => false,
    'add_li_class' => 'menu-dropdown',
    );
wp_nav_menu($args);
```

Please help.

Comment: Can someone help me in fixing this issue please.

Answer (score 0):

`add_li_class` isn't valid arg for `wp_nav_menu`

Try this in your **functions.php**

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'add_my_class_to_nav_menu', 10, 2 );
function add_my_class_to_nav_menu( $classes, $item ){
    $classes[] = 'menu-dropdown';
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i have added add_li_class with another function, this is not an issue, main issue is a class is adding additionally in first ul which is not required if you look over image it's clarify better. https://ibb.co/sFwMwMZ